# MD5 checksums of Android APK files differ. Why?

Tags: java, android, md5, apk, checksum

I notice that if I compile an Android app twice, one right after the other with no changes, that the two APK files have two different MD5 checksums. Unsigned and Signed APK files both yield this same result.

You can open it up as a ZIP file and the contents inside there have identical MD5 checksums in both files, so I'm curious.

What else is there? What is it that is different about these two APK files?

Comment: Maybe APK files store a timestamp of when it was compiled? I'd look through the spec for the APK format and see if something like that exists...

Comment: Sounds likely. Having trouble finding details on APK format. Is APK different from JAR? I'd imagine it would have a few extras.

Comment: the apk files are in fact zip files with a specific file content, just like .jar

Answer (score 13):

The ZIP File Format stores the last modification date inside its header: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers

So the MD5 Sum differs because the header is slighty different.

Comment: So, if you compile an APK, extract the contents, create a ZIP of them, rename it to an APK, it runs? Gotta try this tonight right before I give a whack at doing the same basic thing to a human being.

Comment: in fact yes! `unzip test.apk; rm test.apk; zip -r test.zip ./*; mv test.{zip,apk}; adb install test.apk` works. Even the MD5 Sums are different: 950b9077d8a2a3be45ba207c0c0a2251  test.apk
e0ae339a5ecd3080f8359fc06a4c3e29  test.zip.apk

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "signed" thing makes the MD5 checksum differs ?

Comment: Edited. Turns out this happens in both signed and unsigned APKs.